# iphoney App not showing inheritence? or is it

Tags: css, inheritance, ios-simulator

Does the iphoney simulator app respect css inheritance?
anyone know if there is a way to clear its cache?

example

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="$ThemeDir/css/style.css"/>

    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="$ThemeDir/css/iphone.css" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
```

even if i overide say all the images and hide the header in iphone.css

```
#header, img{dispay:none;
visibility:hidden;
}
```

they still show up on iphoney!!

funny thing is they don't show up on say a blackberry which makes me think its a cache or iphoney issue
http://marketcircle.com/iphoney/

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your css code above. It should be 'display', not 'dispay'.